# How can I move the advanced search into the left sidebar of my homepage?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, advanced-search

How can I move the advanced search into the left sidebar of my homepage? No one seems to have been able to give me an answer so far and I would really like to know how this can be done. Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code in **`local.xml`** to move advanced search to left side bar on home page.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <cms_index_index>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalogsearch/advanced_form" name="catalogsearch_advanced_form" template="catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Into the local.xml?

Comment: Yes. you can put it in local.xml

Comment: It made it appear on the homepage. But now at the top there is breadcrumbs which say 'home/catalog advanced search' which I wouldn't like to happen and also when you search it just goes to 404 page not found

Comment: Copy `catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml` file in to your theme. and modify as per your requirements.

Comment: It is in my theme and it is identical to the original, the search isn't working

Comment: create new file with other name. Copy `catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml`  file content to newly created file. Now you can modify your changes in this file. Change `template=` path with newly created file :-)

Comment: It is working now. Do you know how I can make it so the breadcrumbs dont appear on the homepage?

Comment: Check here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430858/magento-remove-breadcrumbs-from-home-only-with-local-xml

Comment: @OliTuck If this works for you , You can accept this answer. It will helpful to other users

Comment: It is working but it is appearing on all of my pages

Comment: You mean advanced search not working?